# Extract p-value from checkresiduals function

Tags: r, forecasting

I am forecasting with forecast package.Below is results from my forecasting.

```
#CODE 
library(forecast)
      DATA_SET<-data.frame(TEST=c(200,220,200,260,300,290,320,340,360,500,200,300,400,250,350,390,400,450,470,350,300,220,580,450,120,250,360,470)
                           )
      View(DATA_SET)

      # Making TS object
      TS_DATA_SET<-ts(DATA_SET,start=c(2010,1),frequency = 12)

      # Forecasting
      TS_FORECAST<-auto.arima(TS_DATA_SET)
```

So now I want to extract p-value from checkresiduals function into data frame,

```
   #Checking residuals
   checkresiduals(TS_FORECAST, plot = FALSE)

##  Ljung-Box test
##
##   data:  Residuals from ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean
## Q* = 4.5113, df = 4.6, p-value = 0.4237
##
## Model df: 1.   Total lags used: 5.6
```

I am trying with code below but I have problem

```
p-value<-data.frame(checkresiduals(TS_FORECAST, plot = FALSE))
p_value
#data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

So can anybody help me how to extract p-value (p-value = 0.4237) from checkresiduals function into data.frame ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

My first method below got implemented on the 'checkresiduals()' function. Nowadays the function returns the output values by default.

---

old answer:

Unfortunately the function `checkresiduals()` doesn't return values, just `prints()` them. You can see the function by writing `checkresiduals` without brackets. Or you check the [github](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/checkresiduals.R) of the developer.

You can rewrite the function by putting a `return()` in it. I just copy paste the function and insert it at the end:

```
 checkresiduals <- function(object, lag, df=NULL, test, plot=TRUE, ...) {
  showtest <- TRUE
  if (missing(test)) {
    if (is.element("lm", class(object))) {
      test <- "BG"
    } else {
      test <- "LB"
    }
    showtest <- TRUE
  }
  else if (test != FALSE) {
    test <- match.arg(test, c("LB", "BG"))
    showtest <- TRUE
  }
  else {
    showtest <- FALSE
  }

  # Extract residuals
  if (is.element("ts", class(object)) | is.element("numeric", class(object))) {
    residuals <- object
    object <- list(method = "Missing")
  }
  else {
    residuals <- residuals(object)
  }

  if (length(residuals) == 0L) {
    stop("No residuals found")
  }

  if ("ar" %in% class(object)) {
    method <- paste("AR(", object$order, ")", sep = "")
  } else if (!is.null(object$method)) {
    method <- object$method
  } else if ("HoltWinters" %in% class(object)) {
    method <- "HoltWinters"
  } else if ("StructTS" %in% class(object)) {
    method <- "StructTS"
  } else {
    method <- try(as.character(object), silent = TRUE)
    if ("try-error" %in% class(method)) {
      method <- "Missing"
    } else if (length(method) > 1 | base::nchar(method[1]) > 50) {
      method <- "Missing"
    }
  }
  if (method == "Missing") {
    main <- "Residuals"
  } else {
    main <- paste("Residuals from", method)
  }

  if (plot) {
    suppressWarnings(ggtsdisplay(residuals, plot.type = "histogram", main = main, ...))
  }

  # Check if we have the model
  if (is.element("forecast", class(object))) {
    object <- object$model
  }

  if (is.null(object) | !showtest) {
    return(invisible())
  }

  # Seasonality of data
  freq <- frequency(residuals)

  # Find model df
  if(grepl("STL \\+ ", method)){
    warning("The fitted degrees of freedom is based on the model used for the seasonally adjusted data.")
  }
  df <- modeldf(object)

  if (missing(lag)) {
    lag <- ifelse(freq > 1, 2 * freq, 10)
    lag <- min(lag, round(length(residuals)/5))
    lag <- max(df+3, lag)
  }

  if (!is.null(df)) {
    if (test == "BG") {
      # Do Breusch-Godfrey test
      BGtest <- lmtest::bgtest(object, order = lag)
      BGtest$data.name <- main
      print(BGtest)
      return(BGtest)
    }
    else {
      # Do Ljung-Box test
      LBtest <- Box.test(zoo::na.approx(residuals), fitdf = df, lag = lag, type = "Ljung")
      LBtest$method <- "Ljung-Box test"
      LBtest$data.name <- main
      names(LBtest$statistic) <- "Q*"
      print(LBtest)
      cat(paste("Model df: ", df, ".   Total lags used: ", lag, "\n\n", sep = ""))
      return(LBtest)
    }
  }

}
```

you also need the `modeldf()` function from the [github file](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/checkresiduals.R)

```
modeldf <- function(object, ...){
  UseMethod("modeldf")
}

modeldf.Arima <- function(object, ...){
  length(object$coef)
}
```

With this solution you use your original checkresiduals function. Now you can call the p.value with:

```
res_values <- checkresiduals(TS_FORECAST, plot = TRUE)
res_values$p.value
```

You could also just use the `Ljung-Box` and `Breusch-Godfrey test` by yourself and ignore the `checkresiduals()` function, since this is what `checkresiduals()` does.

I thought editing the `checkresiduals()` function is a more handy way, so you can use it like you are used to it. You can paste it in your code and it should do the work. Just make sure you declare the `modeldf()` and `modeldf().Arima` before you call the function. Also it works either test the function does.

---

**Option 2** 
because it's possible:

You could capture the output with `capture.output()`

```
capture.output(checkresiduals(TS_FORECAST, plot = FALSE))[5]
```

> "Q* = 4.8322, df = 5, p-value = 0.4367"

With a grep command it should be possible to extract the p-value without changing the function. Since i'm not familiar with grep, i can't provide a proper answer on this task.

Comment: For completness: I made the changes of my answer a Github commit. It should be changed in the next update.

Comment: This update (from @mischva11) is now a part of `checkresiduals`, so it does return values now. See my answer about converting to a `data.frame`, if needed.

Comment: @Brian Stamper thanks Brian, i updated my Answer and i also like your approach with tidy

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/checkresiduals.R) you can see the inside of `checkresiduals()`.

Unfortunately, as per the docs, it doesn't return a value, so you can't easy extract what you need.

But you can do the same calculation (look at line 125 in the linked repo):

```
Box.test(zoo::na.approx(TS_FORECAST$residuals), type = "Ljung")
```

To access the p-value just use `$p.value`, after you assign the output to a variable.

Note that in my quick example it's a bit different because I used the default values:

```
# r$p.value
# [1] 0.3678976
```

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically need a data frame, now that `checkresiduals` returns an object (thanks to @mischva11) you can use the `tidy` function from the `broom` package to convert that to a `data.frame` (actually a `tibble`, `broom` being part of the `tidyverse`, but that should suffice).

```
> library(broom)
> p_value <- tidy(checkresiduals(TS_FORECAST, plot = FALSE))

        Ljung-Box test

data:  Residuals from ARIMA(0,1,1)
Q* = 0.87319, df = 3, p-value = 0.8319

Model df: 1.   Total lags used: 4

> p_value
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  statistic p.value parameter method        
      <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>         
1     0.873   0.832         3 Ljung-Box test
```

Unfortunately the output is still printed, as shown above, which you may not want. The only way I've found to avoid this is with `invisible(capture.output())`.

```
invisible(capture.output(p_value <- tidy(checkresiduals(TS_FORECAST, plot = FALSE))))
```